# How to stream and play mp3 file from internet url?

Tags: android, streaming, mp3

What's the way to stream (and play) an mp3 audio file from an internet url with Android? Url being something like this: http://somesite.com/somefile.mp3

Thanks!!

Comment: Am I understood you right; you want to stream the mp3 file from the smartphone or maybe you want to record it (from the internet) and play in the meantime?

Comment: I actually just want to stream it from the smartphone. But recording it from the internet would give extra points :)

Comment: Check out the answer to this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775745/android-mediaplayer-stream-online-mp3-file